# MongoDB - Project array subfield with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Having this basic document:

```
{
  "_id": "userID",
  "name": "User Name",
  "profiles": [
    {
      "level": 1,
      "bar": {
        "_id": "bar1ID",
        "name": "Bar Name"
      }
    },
    {
      "level": 1,
      "bar": {
        "_id": "bar2ID",
        "name": "Bar 2 Name"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to remove some fields, and reassign the `bar` field so that it only contains the `_id`:

```
{
  "_id": "userID",
  "profiles": [
    {
      "level": 1,
      "bar": "bar1ID"
    },
    {
      "level": 1,
      "bar": "bar2ID"
    }
  ]
}
```

Matching with the UserID, and using the mongo aggregation framework

Comment: May help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method.

The only stage in the pipeline is the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage where you use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "profiles": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$profiles", 
                "as": "profile", 
                "in": { 
                    "level": "$$profile.level",
                    "bar": "$$profile.bar._id" 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } }
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{
        "_id" : "userID",
        "profiles" : [
                {
                        "level" : 1,
                        "bar" : "bar1ID"
                },
                {
                        "level" : 1,
                        "bar" : "bar2ID"
                }
        ]
}
```